# WordPress RESTful API V2 + AngularJs + Single Post Pagination + Custom Post Type

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, rest, api

Is there any way to get Next/Prev route using WP RESTful V2, while we are on a single post page?

### portfolio-single.html (template)

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">{{title}}</h1>
</div>
<a href="#/portfolio/{{prevPortfolio}}">Prev</a>
<a href="#/portfolio/{{nextPortfolio}}">Next</a>
```

### controller

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('PortfolioCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, wpFactory) {

    wpFactory.getPortfolioSingle($routeParams.id)
        .then(function (succ){
            ignoreLoadingBar: false;
            $scope.title = succ.title.rendered;
            $scope.img = succ.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.large.source_url;

            $scope.currentItemData = succ;
            $scope.currentId = $routeParams.id;


            if($routeParams.id > 0){
                $scope.prevPortfolio = ($routeParams.id) - 1;
            }
            else{
                $scope.prevPortfolio = $scope.currentItemData.length-1;
            }

            if($routeParams.id < $scope.currentItemData.length-1){
                $scope.nextPortfolio = ($routeParams.id)+1;
            }
            else{
                $scope.nextPortfolio = 0;
            }

        }, function error(err) {
            console.log('Errror: ', err);
        });
  });
```

NOTE:
I am using WordPress as backend only and develop complete separate frontend using Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to route change event with the following code:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
    console.log(current); // Current route information
    console.log(next);    // Future route information
});
```

See the [`$route` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) for more information.

---

### [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/j4sb8abd/1/)

Comment: Thanks @mistalis. But I guess it's not good practice to use $rootScope but still if you can share JS Fiddle example, would be great help.

Comment: @KushalJayswal You are right, you should avoid the use of `$rootScope` as possible. But at least, it is the way to access route change events... :)

Comment: okay make sense but still requesting you to create a quick demo https://jsfiddle.net. Thanks.

Comment: @KushalJayswal Here is a quick demo. Open the console  when testing :) http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/j4sb8abd/1/

Comment: Yes I am getting console but not able to switch through the next and previous ID of the portfolio in the object. Let me create dummy JSON and create a fiddle to get more clear on the requirement...

Comment: @KushalJayswal Don't you say you made a Fiddle?

Comment: yes I tried to implement in existing code. Once get time to create fiddle will be sharing the link. Thanks.

Comment: @KushalJayswal What's new?